# Android Notification bar self ad

Tags: android

Is it valid to ask for purchase of paid version of the app via notification bar ?
I m planning to do it less often say once in a day

Can anyone please comment

Comment: Read the following: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [**ADMOB policy**](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

Apps and their **ads must not display advertisements through system level notifications** on the user’s device, unless the notifications derive from an integral feature provided by the installed app (e.g., an airline app that notifies users of special deals, or a game that notifies users of in-game promotions).

But if you are just prompt user to buy a paid version of your own application, I think it is **acceptable** for the policy but not welcomed by user.